# Installing MRBAYES 3.2 on linux

Tags: linux, bioinformatics

I'm trying to get MRBAYES 3.2 to work on my linux computer (CentOs 6.4).

I'm following the directions to compile the program from source from CompileInstructions.txt. It tells me to do the following:

```
> autoconf
> ./configure --enable-mpi=yes
> make
```

However, when I do >make it tells me that

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Also I have tried to target make to the Makefile.in (make -f Makefile.in) but that doesn't work either. Has anyone installed MRBAYES?

Comment: Have you checked that `./configure` succeeded and did not print any errors for you?

Comment: Actually it didn't succeed so that is the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be mrbayes required the BEAGLE library in order to properly configure. Thus a makefile wasn't created, and make install couldn't run.